# Failure to Remove H2 Dependency with Apache ignite 2.14.0

Tags: java, ignite

With the Apache Ignite 2.13.0 release. They introduced a new  beta sql engine to replace the existing h2 sql engine. Unfortunately it still had a dependency on the h2 indexing module. With the 2.14 release it supposedly removed this dependency. Now I am trying to remove the h2 package completely (due to critical code vulnerabilities in the h2 package). Does anyone know how to remove h2 completely from a java built ignite project?

Documentation:
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-calcite

Here is how I am setting my ignite configuration explicitely avoiding the h2 engine

```
igniteConfiguration.setSqlConfiguration(
                new SqlConfiguration().setQueryEnginesConfiguration(
                        new CalciteQueryEngineConfiguration().setDefault(true)
                )
        );
```

EDIT:

To resolve our issue we had to remove the dependencies imports for org.apache.ignite:ignite-slf4j:2.14.0 and org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring:2.14.0

Answer (score 2):

In case you configured only one query engine, which is `CalciteQueryEngineConfiguration`, then the `ignite-indexing` dependency can be removed from your project, as a result, you will no longer have the `h2` in the list of dependencies.

Here is a dependency section example:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
      <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-calcite</artifactId>
      <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

You can execute `mvn dependency:tree` to check the actual list of dependencies.

Also, I should mention that the Calcite-based query engine is currently in beta status.

Comment: I have confirmed h2 is not a dependency and it is not in the classpath.

However, I am still getting a runtime error on `Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConfiguration);`



```igniteConfiguration.setSqlConfiguration(
                new SqlConfiguration().setQueryEnginesConfiguration(
                        new CalciteQueryEngineConfiguration().setDefault(true)
                )
        );
        Ignite toReturn = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConfiguration);```


Error is 
```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.message.DbException
```

Comment: You can check an example here: https://github.com/ibelyakov/ignite-no-h2-example

Comment: Thanks for the response @Igor Belyakov.

Turns out the issue was we included the ignite-slf4j and ignite-spring packages. For some reason this was causing the sql engine to be h2 even after explicitly setting it like I stated above.

Now we just have to resolve the issue with the existing sql queries erroring out on 
```50000: org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlAbstractParserImpl.setTimeUnitCodes(Ljava/util/Map;)V```

Comment: Can you please provide the query and a full stack trace for the error?

Comment: The issue was that we forced the upgrade of calcite-core to 1.32.0 because the provided version (1.30.0) has a critical vulnerability

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-39135

Is there any plan an addressing this in a future release? Of is there some work around you know of to get off version 1.30.0

Comment: ```java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlAbstractParserImpl.setTimeUnitCodes(Ljava/util/Map;)V
 at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.<init>(SqlParser.java:73) ~[calcite-core-1.32.0.jar:1.32.0]
 at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.create(SqlParser.java:126) ~[calcite-core-1.32.0.jar:1.32.0]
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.calcite.util.Commons.parse(Commons.java:220) ~[ignite-calcite-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
 at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.calcite.util.Commons.parse(Commons.java:204)... 
```

Comment: @Towelie It's been fixed for the next version (2.15) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-17722